# Нужно слушать TCP сокет с ПК на android

Tags: tcp

Вопросов пока несколько:
1. Как определить, на каком порту вещает программа с ПК. localhost и?
2. Как и чем слушать? Асинхронно? Может есть какая книга или статья?
3. В идеале и обратно тоже посылать пакеты. Вопрос, как?
Спасибо!!
Часто примеры вижу клиент-сервер и оба на Андроиде, а мне нужно именно клиент, так как программа не моя, а сторонняя...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Никак, только если знать заранее. Ну вариант с перебором портов на сервере, но это почти бред... Поэтому вы заранее должно знать, на каком порту висит ваш сервер.
2. [Тут](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/java_http_web/article02.html) основы, берёте просто клиентскую часть, если у вас уже реализован сервер. [Тут](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Network/0080__Java_Network_Asynchronous_Socket_Channels.htm) можно посмотреть асинхронный клиент.
3. Клиент-серверная архитектура, вы посылаете сообщение на сервер, он вам что-то отвечает. Если не закрываете соединение с сервером, он вам может еще что-то досылать в сокет

Еще [ссылочка](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sending-and-Receiving-Data-with-Sockets). И по поводу примеров, берёте из статьи только клиента и все. Все tcp - серверы как минимум сходятся в одном, они работают по tcp/ip, на сокетах.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую!!!

Comment: Нашел на просторах инета вопрос: I used before "AsynchronousSocketChannel" class on Java. I needed today and i look that but i can not see this class. What do you think about this? и ответ гугла:
we don't currently support any of the asynchronous i/o stuff.
ссылка здесь: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56816

Answer (score 0):

На первый вопрос отвечу:
0. Запускаете командную строку под админовскими правами
1. Запускаете tasklist > имяфайла.txt, в нём определяете PID вашего процесса
2. запускаете netstat -aon > имяфайла.txt , затем в полученном текстовом файле ищете ваш PID и получаете адреса, порты и т.п. для него

При желании можно написать программу, которая будет запускать это всё, а затем парсить получаемый файл.